# How to insert ignore with 100+ input values

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i'm learning Java hibernate,
found an example of "insert ignore",

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLA (ID, VAR) VALUES (:id, :var)");
UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
query.setParameter("id", id);
String var = "abcde";
query.setParameter("var", var);
query.executeUpdate();
```

This will "insert ignore" 1 entry.
I may have 100+ var as input, but only 1 or 2 will not be in the existing table, i don't know which ones.

If i set Parameters of 100 of values with a loop, it may work. But is there a better may ? given i may just need to insert 1 or 2 of them really.

Or i should ask this: given a list of 100 var string, find out the a few not in existing table, without using loop.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25480573/5066625

Comment: Just to be clear, you use the loop to build a single query, right? You don't execute 100 queries?

Comment: @Strawberry  yes i expect 1 query if it's possible, how to do it is my question

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MySQL `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` feature.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA (ID, VAR) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=ID;
```

I'm not familiar with java or hibernate, hence my answer being a raw query. If you need help figuring out the exact syntax,  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913341/can-hibernate-work-with-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update-syntax) question might be a good resource for it.

Also, generally speaking, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is much safer than `INSERT IGNORE` because the latter will ignore **all** errors, while the former will only ignore duplicate inserts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: my concern is, the INSERT string is so long if i have 100 vars and uuid, won't this hit some max string length ?

Comment: I don't think so.  I run a similar query that is roughly 13000 bytes long, so I don't think it will matter.

Comment: I think I'd try to find a way to use the values option with this solution

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?